# Shopware 6 scheduled task not running

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

I don't get a scheduled task to run in my module. I followed the documentation:

https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/scheduled-tasks

and:

https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/references-internals/core/module/tasks

But it seems the task never runs (I added logging to make sure). The task is showing up in the 'scheduled_task' database table with the status 'queued' and a last_execution_time of 'NULL'. It looks like the other scheduled tasks (like the delete_newsletter_recipient_task, requeue_dead_messages, product_export_generate_task, shopware.sitemap_generate and shopware.elasticsearch.create.alias) are running however. Also if I manualy run the 'DownloadFeedTaskHandler' 'run' method the code is working as expected.

I found this (German) forum post with more or less the same problem, but no solution:

https://forum.shopware.com/discussion/67988/scheduled-task-hat-den-queued-status

I checked the dead_messages table but it doesn't have any records.

Any idea how to go from here?

My relevant files look like:

custom/plugins/AWSamplePlugin/src/Resources/config/services.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="AW\SamplePlugin\ScheduledTask\DownloadFeedTask">
            <tag name="shopware.scheduled.task" />
        </service>
        <service id="AW\SamplePlugin\ScheduledTask\DownloadFeedTaskHandler">
            <argument type="service" id="scheduled_task.repository" />
            <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService" />
            <argument type="service" id="logger" />
            <argument type="service" id="sales_channel.repository" />
            <tag name="messenger.message_handler" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

custom/plugins/AWSamplePlugin/src/ScheduledTask/DownloadFeedTask.php:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace AW\SamplePlugin\ScheduledTask;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\MessageQueue\ScheduledTask\ScheduledTask;

class DownloadFeedTask extends ScheduledTask
{
    public static function getTaskName(): string
    {
        return 'aw.download_feed';
    }

    public static function getDefaultInterval(): int
    {
        return 60; // Every minute
    }
}
```

custom/plugins/AWSamplePlugin/src/ScheduledTask/DownloadFeedTaskHandler.php:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace AW\SamplePlugin\ScheduledTask;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\MessageQueue\ScheduledTask\ScheduledTaskHandler;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class DownloadFeedTaskHandler extends ScheduledTaskHandler
{
    protected $systemConfigService;
    protected $logger;
    protected $salesChannelRepository;

    public function __construct(
        EntityRepositoryInterface $scheduledTaskRepository,
        SystemConfigService $systemConfigService,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        EntityRepositoryInterface $salesChannelRepository
    ) {
        $logger->info('__construct');
        parent::__construct($scheduledTaskRepository);
        $this->systemConfigService = $systemConfigService;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->salesChannelRepository = $salesChannelRepository;
        $logger->info('__construct END');
    }

    public static function getHandledMessages(): iterable
    {
        return [ DownloadFeedTask::class ];
    }

    public function run(): void
    {
        $this->logger->info('RUNNING!');
        echo "ScheduledTask run";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the ScheduledTask is stuck in queued status most probably the generated message by that task was not handled.

To consume messages use the `bin/console messenger:consume`, you can use the `-vv` flag to see the messages that get's processed.

For more information on how to consume messages refer to this [docs article](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/references-internals/core/module/queue#consuming-messages).

This is necessary because the `bin/console scheduled-task:run` command will only check which scheduled tasks need to run and take care of the scheduling, but in order to actually run those tasks the command will dispatch messages to the messages queue und the task then get executed when you consume those messages from the queue.